# python logging: difference between 2.6 and 2.7

Tags: python, linux, logging, fedora

I must be doing something wrong: is there a difference between the `basicConfig` of python 2.6 and 2.7?

Under python 2.6, a `basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)` will not send info msg to stdout whilst under 2.7 it does.

Could somebody explain what I am doing wrong??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a long shot, but you should make sure there aren't any logging calls before the call to `basicConfig()`. That's a common `logging` gotcha, though I'm not sure why it will work with 2.7

Comment: Just found a race condition... thanks for your suggestion which put me on the right track.